# Send Invoice Reminder based on company settings

Tags: laravel, queue, scheduled-tasks

Hope you guys are doing well. I have faced an issue I need a better solution. Please read the description below, I have an invoice management system where companies can register and will get their own dashboard where they can update their own settings and can create invoices for their clients. Now I have to send the due invoice reminder mail. Now, the problem is as companies can set the interval.

Company A wants to send the invoice 7 days before the due and then before 2 days of the due total of 2 reminders. Company B wants to send the invoice 5 days before the due and then before 1 day of the due date total of 2 reminders.

As I have one scheduled job for checking this, If I query all unpaid invoices with company and company settings and check then check the date and then send the mail and in case I have 200k invoices of companies it will be costly.

How should query the invoice or schdule the job.

Thanks in advance.

Please write your approach to this problem. It will help me a lot.

Comment: As I am thinking i would probably set a maximum of how much before the due is allowed to set the email. For example 2 weeks and then when you do the query you can query just that ones to improve performance. Also maybe add some functionality like queue to schedule email sending upon invoice create or update, and then remove it if the invoice gets paid (so still on update). Just an rough idea

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.